# сортировка очереди на основе массива

Tags: c++, сортировка, очередь

Прошу помочь реализовать сортировку очереди, реализованную на основе массива. Сортировка может быть любой, интересно было бы посмотреть быструю сортировку. Моя реализация очереди на основе массива.

```
class Queue
{
private:
    int size;
    int *queueArray;//одномерный массив для хранения элемнтов очереди
    int start;//для хранения первого элемнта очереди
    int end;//для хранение последнего элемента очереди
    int countItems;// количество элементов в очереди
public:
    Queue(int s){//конструктор
        size=s;
        queueArray=new int[size];//выделенение памяти под храние s элемнетов
        start=0;
        end=-1;
        countItems=0;
    }
    void push (int x){ //добавление элемента (в конец)
        queueArray[++end]=x;
        countItems++;
    }
    int pop(){//удаление элементов (из начала) и получение доступа к первому элементу
        int temp=queueArray[start++];
        countItems--;
        return temp;
    }
    void print(){
        if(countItems==0)
            cout<<"Queue is empty\n";
        else if(countItems==1)
            cout<<"1:"<<queueArray[start];
        if(start<end){
            for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
                cout<<i+1<<"-ый элемент:"<<queueArray[i]<<endl;
        }
        
    }
    
};
```

Comment: `std::sort` чем не устраивает?

Comment: Очень странная очередь. Память после удаления будет простаивать. Может лучше сделать на основе связного списка? Ну и нужно помнить о [Правиле трёх](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @Zhihar ну если это очередь, то, если мне не изменяет память, ее нельзя отсортировать стандартным алгоритмом, так как для этого нужен random access итератор, что у очереди вряд ли будет (да и должно быть)

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, конечно, но всегда можно очередь запихнуть в массив, массив отсортировать и потом обратно запихнуть в очередь (ну или очереди добавить нужные итераторы) - ведь для сортировки все равно необходимо все элементы очереди просмотреть

Comment: @Zhihar а можно вообще не париться с очередями и сразу запихнуть в массив... Вот только во-первых, это не производительно, во-вторых это никакого отношения к вопросу не имеет

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, мне кажется очередь в принципе производительно не отсортировать - если исключить массивы и оставить только очередь(очереди) и промежуточное значение, то сортировка будет походить на решение задачи о ханойских башнях, в добавок в вопросе явно говорится `сортировка на основе массива`, что как мне кажется и означает - выгрузить все в массив и отсортировать или определить произвольный доступ к элементам и отсортировать

Comment: @Zhihar вы, однако, избирательно скопировали) Вы слово одно пропустили `сортировка ОЧЕРЕДИ на основе массива` - согласитесь, это совсем не то же, что `сортировка на основе массива`

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch, а какая разница - понятно что очередь сделанная через массив имелось в виду, но это как раз и дает возможность провести обычную сортировку (с некоторыми корректировками относительно начала очереди)

Comment: Как это - **сортировать очередь?** Все, что можно с ней делать - по определению! - только вставлять элементы в хвост и забирать из головы...